# I'm looking for a string in a file, seems to not be working

Tags: python, list, file

My function first calculates all possible anagrams of the given word. Then, for each of these anagrams, it checks if they are valid words, but checking if they equal to any of the words in the wordlist.txt file. The file is a giant file with a bunch of words line by line. So I decided to just read each line and check if each anagram is there. However, it comes up blank. Here is my code:

```
def perm1(lst):
    if len(lst) == 0:
        return []
    elif len(lst) == 1:
        return [lst]
    else:
        l = []
        for i in range(len(lst)):
            x = lst[i]
            xs = lst[:i] + lst[i+1:]
            for p in perm1(xs):
                l.append([x] + p)
        return l
def jumbo_solve(string):
    '''jumbo_solve(string) -> list
    returns list of valid words that are anagrams of string'''
    passer = list(string)
    allAnagrams = []
    validWords = []
    for x in perm1(passer):
        allAnagrams.append((''.join(x)))
    for x in allAnagrams:
        if x in open("C:\\Users\\Chris\\Python\\wordlist.txt"):
            validWords.append(x)
    return(validWords)
print(jumbo_solve("rarom"))
```

If have put in many print statements to debug, and the passed in list, "allAnagrams", is fully functional. For example, with the input "rarom, one valid anagram is the word "armor", which is contained in the wordlist.txt file. However, when I run it, it does not detect if for some reason. Thanks again, I'm still a little new to Python so all the help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Note, your `perm1` function can be replaced with a call to `itertools.permutations()`.

Comment: Your solution has a very high complexity which can be reduced in a number of ways depending on various constraints bro....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed a tiny but important aspect of:

```
word in open("C:\\Users\\Chris\\Python\\wordlist.txt")
```

This will search the file line by line, as if `open(...).readlines()` was used, and attempt to match the entire line, **with** `'\n'` **in the end**. Really, anything that demands iterating over `open(...)` works like `readlines()`.

You would need 
    `x+'\n' in open("C:\\Users\\Chris\\Python\\wordlist.txt")`

if the file is a list of words on separate lines to make this work to fix what you have, but it's inefficient to do this on every function call. Better to do once:

```
wordlist = open("C:\\Users\\Chris\\Python\\wordlist.txt").read().split('\n')
```

this will create a list of words if the file is a `'\n'` separated word list. Note you can use

```
`readlines()`
```

instead of `read().split('\n')`, but this will keep the `\n` on every word, like you have, and you would need to include that in your search as I show above. Now you can use the list as a global variable or as a function argument.

```
if x in wordlist: stuff
```

Note Graphier raised an important suggestion in the comments. A set:

```
wordlist = set(open("C:\\Users\\Chris\\Python\\wordlist.txt").read().split('\n'))
```

Is better suited for a word lookup than a list, since it's O(word length).

Comment: Since you are reading the file only once, might as well store it in a `set` to get `O(1)` time complexity for `in`.

Comment: Thanks a lot kabanus! Your answer was really helpful and I completely understand why my program messed up here. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have used the following code in the wrong way:

```
 if x in open("C:\\Users\\Chris\\Python\\wordlist.txt"):
```

Instead, try the following code, it should solve your problem:

```
with open("words.txt", "r") as file:
    lines = file.read().splitlines()

    for line in lines:
        # do something here
```

Comment: Oops, thanks for clarity on that. I wasn't aware you could use file objects in that way.

Answer (score 0):

So, putting all advice together, your code could be as simple as:

```
from itertools import permutations

def get_valid_words(file_name):
    with open(file_name) as f:
        return set(line.strip() for line in f)

def jumbo_solve(s, valid_words=None):
    """jumbo_solve(s: str) -> list
    returns list of valid words that are anagrams of `s`"""
    if valid_words is None:
        valid_words = get_valid_words("C:\\Users\\Chris\\Python\\wordlist.txt")
    return [word for word in permutations(s) if word in valid_words]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(jumbo_solve("rarom"))
```